# Is it possible to retrieve the values from cellEditorParams to colorize the column cells in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, html, css, ag-grid

I am trying to colorize the whole cell based on the value the user selected from a dropdown menu within the cell.
This is the column definition where I defined the dropDown menu using cellEditorParams and colorized the cell using the cellStyle.

```
{
  headerName: 'Year',
  field: 'year',
  width: 500,
  editable: true,
  cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
  cellEditorParams: {
    values: [
      '',
      '1 - Faible',
      '2 - Moyen ',
      '3 - Significatif',
      '4 - Elevé'
    ]
  },
  cellStyle(params) {
    const color = 'blue';
    return {
      'background-color': color
    };
  }
}
```

Which gives me this:
[image]
[image]

I would like to colorize the cell based on the value chosen by the user.
i.e: If he chooses:  '1 - Faible', the color of the cell will become: green
If he chooses: '2 - Moyen ', the color of the cell will become: orange

And so on and so forth.
So here's where I need your help:
1/ How can I retrieve the value the user has chose?
2/ How can I use it in the cellStyle?
3/ Am I even doing this the right way?

Comment: Have you looked at cell renderers? https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/

Comment: make use of `cellValueChanged` event to retrieve what value use choosen

Answer (score 0):

[Working sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/AUOZRhbEHEhIBW6iaUWr?p=preview)

There is built-in option in ag-grid called [`cellClassRules`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styling/#cellClassRules).

```
 this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 300,
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor",
        cellEditorParams: {
          values: [
            "Bob",
            "Harry",
            "Sally",
            "Mary",
            "John",
            "Jack",
            "Sue",
            "Sean",
            "Niall",
            "Albert",
            "Fred",
            "Jenny",
            "Larry"
          ]
        },
        cellClassRules: {
           // apply green to Bob
           'rag-green-outer': function(params) { return params.value === "Bob"},
           // apply amber Harry
           'rag-amber-outer': function(params) { return params.value === "Harry"},
           // apply red to Mary
           'rag-red-outer': function(params) { return params.value === "Mary"}
       },
      }
]
```

**style.css**

```
.rag-green-outer {
  background-color: green;
}

.rag-amber-outer {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rag-red-outer{ 
  background-color: red;
}
```

You can also try `cellValueChanged` event. Thats another aproach.

Comment: The agRichSelectCellEditor doesn't work. It had to be replaced with:agSelectCellEditor. And in this case the cell doesn't get colorized

Comment: You also have to add this, but it will only colorize the text:

Comment: cellRenderer(params) {
      return '<span class="rag-element">' + params.value + '</span>';
  }

Comment: I just posted an answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution I wanted with minimal code and no cellRenderer definition needed:

```
 {
  headerName: 'Name',
  field: 'name',
  width: 300,
  editable: true,
  cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
  cellEditorParams: {
    values: [
      'Bob',
      'Harry',
      'Sally',
      'Mary',
      'John',
      'Jack',
      'Sue',
      'Sean',
      'Niall',
      'Albert',
      'Fred',
      'Jenny',
      'Larry'
    ]
  },
cellStyle(params) {
var color;
if (params.value=== 'Harry') {color='yellow'}
else
if (params.value=== 'Bob') {color='green'}
else
if (params.value=== 'Mary') {color='red'}
return {
    'background-color': color
}},
```

}
This works perfectly if you select Harry, the whole cell color will become yellow :)